Server Manager shows Online - Access is Denied
I have a Hyper-V VM with a DC, a Server, and a Windows 10 Workstation. I was meddling around with the DC, removing the built-in Administrator account from the Distributed COM Users and adding it back. Since then, the server manager will not add/remove roles or features. It will not refresh. Essentially, the server manager is useless. These are the errors I get.
Configuration refresh failed with the following error: Access is Denied
Refresh failed with the following error: Access is Denied
Refresh failed with the following error: Provider load failure
Things to note:

The Administrator account password was reset.
Can login using the Administrator account.
Can login to the other server using the account.
Add the DC to the server's server manager, but the error prevails.
Administrator is a member of
Administrators
ADSync Admins
Distributed COM Users
Domain Admins
Domain Users
Enterprise Admins
Group Policy Creator Owners
Schema Admins

I am unable to find an answer for this error. Any help would be much appreciated.
Note: I am open to creating a new DC, migrating the FSMO roles, moving the data, and everything. But I wish to keep that as a last resort.
